# How can I let a user create more then one input and still store it in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My question title might've been confusing but here is what I am trying to do. Basically, I would like to allow a user to create past work, but I understand that people might have had more than 1 past career.

How could I allow them to click a "+" to add more work history and still save that data into Mongo with mongoose?

**Any help is appreciated**

Notice: I am not very good at explaining so please let me know immediately if you do not understand what I mean.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can tell us what you've tried and what specifically isn't working. Have you got the "+" button working to add more inputs to your form? Is the form submitting to the server? And what does your mongoose schema look like?

Comment: I haven't tried anything just been researching and nothing comes up.

Comment: I am wondering if I would still be able to store all the fields a user adds to the schema without the properties being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can persist an array in mongodb using Mongoose, it's one of the valid data types. So you could conceptually create a schema of work, eg:

```
const WorkSchema = new Schema({ jobTitle: String, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, description: String});
```

And then your user schema might define similarly:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({ lastName: String, firstName: String, work: [WorkSchema] });
```

A user model instance could then add work instances individually:

```
const user = new User();
user.work.push({jobTitle: 'manager', startDate: new Date()});
```

or en masse:

```
const user = new User();
user.work = [... array of work instances... ];
```

As for partially filled out info, that's entirely up to your validation logic.